Execution service out of memory
I have an application that reads very large CSV files, with over 100 million records in one file, and sends appropriately formatted JSON to another service. When I run this code, it initially processes smoothly, but after a few seconds, the processing starts to slow down until it eventually comes to a halt, and an 'out of memory' error occurs. How can I prevent this error?
private val nThreads = 10 
    private val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)
    private val manager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()
    private val httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(manager)
        .build()

    fun send(body: String) {
        val post = HttpPost(URI.create("url"))
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        post.entity = StringEntity(body)
        httpClient.execute(post)
    }


    fun process() {
        val lines = AtomicInteger()
        ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:file.csv").bufferedReader().forEachLine {
            lines.getAndIncrement()
            if (lines.get() > 1) {
                val records = it.split(",")
                executorService.execute {
                    send(generate(records[0], records[1], records[2], records[3]))
                }
                if (lines.get() % 10000 == 0) println(lines)
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdown()
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow()
            }
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            System.err.println(e.message)
            executorService.shutdownNow()
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
        }
    }
    private fun generate(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, dateTime: String): String {
"""JSON TEXT """
 }


How large is the input file? You could always just allocate more memory to the JVM.

You are sending the body over multiple threads? how that works?

Good:

You are using a BufferedReader to gradually read from the enormous CSV file.
You are using an executor service to manage your tasks.

Bad:

You are using the Executor#execute method that may or may not run the task on a background thread.
You are overwhelming the executor service with a zillion task objects, each populated with a row of data from your CSV. So you have effectively loaded the entire CSV file's contents into RAM within the JVM. Hence your out-of-memory error.

Avoid Executor, use ExecutorService
Regarding the first problem, read the Javadoc for execute:

The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

That third case, “in the calling thread", means the task would not make use of any background threads.
The solution is to call instead the sub-interface ExecutorService methods rather than that Executor method.
Throttle creation of tasks, not just their execution
For the second problem, you have successfully throttled your tasks’ execution. But you neglected to throttle their creation.
Your limit of 10 threads is throttling the execution of your tasks, but your forEachLine call is not throttled. The forEachLine call results in immediately creating a task object for each and every of the 100,000,000 rows, all resident in memory long before the executor service gets around to executing those tasks.
My first thought about how to throttle their creation is to use a Semaphore with a limited number of permits. In your code that creates the task, try to acquire one of the permits. If available, the task object in instantiated and submitted to the executor service.
Example app
Here is an example app.
public class CsvProcessor
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        CsvProcessor app = new CsvProcessor( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        final int MAXIMUM_THREADS = 10;
        final Semaphore semaphoreToThrottleTaskCreation = new Semaphore( MAXIMUM_THREADS );
        final Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/basil_dot_work/HundredMillion.csv" );
        try (
                final BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
                final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAXIMUM_THREADS )
        )
        {
            bufferedReader.lines( ).forEach(
                    ( String line ) -> {
                        try
                        {
                            semaphoreToThrottleTaskCreation.acquire( );  // Blocks until a permit becomes available.
                            executorService.submit( ( ) -> {
                                try
                                {
                                    // Simulate work load for generating JSON.
                                    try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( 1 , 10 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
                                    // Simulate work load for making HTTP POST request.
                                    try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( 1 , 10 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
                                    System.out.println( "Processing line: " + line );
                                } finally
                                {
                                    semaphoreToThrottleTaskCreation.release( );  // Returns a permit back to the pool.
                                }
                            } );
                        } catch ( InterruptedException e )
                        {
                            throw new RuntimeException( e );
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}

Notice how we used try-with-resources syntax to automatically close our executor service.
I only tried this with a data file of twelve rows. So not fully tested. But should get you going in the right direction.
When run:
Processing line: 2, Bob, Barker, 2023-02-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 10, Janice, Anderson, 2023-01-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 9, Ivar, Channing, 2023-03-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 7, Gregory, Anderson, 2023-01-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 3, Carol, Channing, 2023-03-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 8, Harriet, Barker, 2023-02-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 6, Francine, Channing, 2023-03-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 4, Davis, Anderson, 2023-01-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 1, Alice, Anderson, 2023-01-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 11, Keith, Barker, 2023-02-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 5, Edie, Barker, 2023-02-23T12:34Z
Processing line: 12, Lisa, Channing, 2023-03-23T12:34Z

Use semaphore to control both creation and execution of tasks
If you reread that code, you may notice that our semaphore for throttling creation of our task objects is actually doing double-duty by also limiting execution of our tasks.
So we do not really need to specify a number of threads to be pooled by our executor service. We could replace Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAXIMUM_THREADS ) with Executors.newCachedThreadPool(). This alternate executor service implementation creates any number of threads. But given our use of Semaphore, we know the maximum number of threads in use will be 10. (Assuming we ignore the slight moment between our release of the semaphore and the exiting of our task’s execution.)
Virtual Threads
We could go a step further and consider using virtual threads rather than platform threads for this work. These tasks described in the Question are making network calls. Such calls involve much blocking. That makes them a candidate for virtual threads. If the tasks are not CPU-bound, do not involve long-running use of synchronized or native code (JNI, Foreign Functions), then we should be using virtual threads for maximum performance.
You can reasonably have millions of virtual threads at a time, given that they are so efficient with both memory and CPU. However, we do not want to overwhelm the server being hit by our HTTP POST requests, nor do we want to recreate our problem of running out of memory by loading all 100 million lines in memory. So we need to leave our Semaphore throttle in place. All we need is to replace the Executors. … call. Change this:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAXIMUM_THREADS )

… to this:
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()

For more info, see Managing Throughput with Virtual Threads - Sip of Java by Billy Korando (2024-02).

By the way, parsing an enormous CSV file line-by-line to generate JSON for submission over a network web-services call is an extremely inefficient way to communicate data. Consider an alternatives. At a minimum, transmit a batch of lines rather than single lines. Even better, skip CSV parsing, JSON generation, and web-service calls: Upload the file directly using a database’s bulk-data feature like COPY in Postgres.

A truly great answer. It really covers everything: addressing the problems, referring to the documentation, providing many solutions and also an implementation. This is how answers should look.

You have 100 million records and for each record you make a POST request: No wonder your client is going down. The server too, I presume, looks like a massive DOS attack.
Since you cannot send as fast over the network as you call httpClient.execute() the POST requests must be buffered. That uses up memory, any when that runs low the JVM garbage collects much more often which costs time and is probably the reason why it all slows down. Until there is no memory left and your program crashes. You can try to increase the memory available to the JVM but this won't solve the real problem: You make way too many HTTP requests.
Either stagger the requests to only make around 10 requests per second (then your program won't crash but it would take around 4 months to finish), or send the records in bulk. I hope the endpoint supports that, otherwise you are doomed.
Even when the endpoint supports sending records in bulk you probably shouldn't send all of them at once. You didn't specify the size of the CSV file (in GB), but as JSON it will be much larger, with indentation (which you should strip!) probably double the size. That's how much in total? 10 Gigabyte? Even with HTTP compression (which you should make sure is enabled) that would still be several GB. I'm not sure HTTP POST would be suited for this amount of data. Splitting the payload in chunks of, say, around 100MB seems more reasonable to start with. Also keep in mind that every chunk must be stored (uncompressed) in memory in its entirety until it was sent. So don't increase this too much unless the JVM has enough memory available.
Using multiple threads is of no use here, on the contrary: The bottleneck is the network, not the CPU. But if you have 10 threads running in parallel this will also increase the memory footprint 10-fold.

Exactly what I was thinking. He could use an asynchronous client to await responses for each post (assuming he can only post a single row at a time) but that would likely take an extremely long time. Other than bundling the posts, I don't think there's a better solution here.

Incorrect. The executor service is limited to 10 threads. So there is not 100 million POST requests. Only 10 or less POST requests exist at a time.

@BasilBourque: Yes, there are only ever 10 HTTP requests on the network adapter at any given time (as limited by the 10 threads), but executorService.execute is called for each line in the CSV file, and if I didn't misread the question that's over 100 million lines. So there will also be 100 million HTTP requests in total, executed 10 at a time. And since executorService.execute is called much faster than the requests can be handled, for each waiting request the lambda's capture must still be kept in memory. And they each contain a HttpPost object.

The tasks ore not executed 10 at a time. They are not batched. When any one request ends, another begins. There are always 10 or less requests pending at a time from this app. So no  suspicion of DOS attack would be warranted.

100 million HTTP requests in rapid succession, even when only ever 10 of them are running at the same time, would certainly qualify as a DOS attack in my book unless this is what the endpoint is specifically designed for. A lot of APIs will be rate-limited anyways, but those that aren't could be easily overwhelmed by this, not being able to timely serve requests from other clients anymore.


I have an application that reads very large CSV files, with over 100 million records in one file ... the processing starts to slow down until it eventually comes to a halt, and an 'out of memory' error occurs.

The trick is to use a bounded thread-pool.  The standard Executors methods have an internal queue which has no limit.
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int numThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(numThreads, numThreads,
        0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(/* no limit */);
}

Your 100 million records will go into the queue which can easily fill memory.  Under the covers the Executors methods are just building a ThreadPoolExecutor.  You can initialize the ThreadPoolExecutor with a bounded queue by doing something like:
ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000 /* limit */));

Then, when you submit your jobs to the pool, after the threads start with the jobs any additional jobs will going into the bounded queue until it reaches 1000 queued jobs.  However once the queue is full you get a RejectedExecutionException so you need to also set a rejection handler:
poolExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        try {
            // This does the actual put into the queue. If the queue
            // is full then this causes submit() to block.
            executor.getQueue().put(r);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
});

Now the first N jobs will be run by the threads, any additional jobs will be queued up to 1000, and if the queue is full the thread that is submitting the jobs will block until there is space.
